# NodeJS mssql with params on request.input; why is it still giving RequestError: Must declare the _____ variable "@____"

Tags: node.js, sql-server, parameters

I have a `connection.request().query()` that works when there is no params, so the configuration works to pass the query.

BUT, when I use a few @param_name in the query, it says the variable isn't declared.

> RequestError: Must declare the table variable "@table".

I have put the params into the request object by using the  `request.input('param_name', val)` as explained in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value)

Why am I still receiving the error that they're not declared? This error is happening at the line `sqlRequest.query(query)`.

Here is my code.

```
module.exports = {
    tdaas: async (query, params) => {
        try {
            console.log({query, params})
            const connection = await tdaasSqlServer.connect(tdaasConfiguration())
            const sqlRequest = await connection.request()
            
            if (params != null) {
                sqlRequest.input('table',  'api_service_request');
                sqlRequest.input('requestId', params.requestId);
                sqlRequest.input('requestStatus', params.requestStatus.toString());
                
            }

            let tdaasResponse = await sqlRequest.query(query);
            return tdaasResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return error;
        } finally {
            tdaasSqlServer.close()
        }
    },
```

And here is what the args passed to the function look like (as console logged in line 4 above)

```
{
  query: 'update @table set status= @requestStatus where id = @requestId',    
  params: {
    table: 'api_service_request',
    requestStatus: 'Completed',
    requestId: 145
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use scalar variables to hold view, table and column names like that.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL (make sure to sanitize and/or escape the object names). But this indicates a design flaw: why do you have multiple tables with the same two columns that you need to access? Should all the data be in a single table?

Comment: Thanks you @AlwaysLearning, after seeing your response, I found in the documentation that you're correct. Can't use a variable for the table or column names.